# How to show scrollbar inside ui-select dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, ui-select

I am using ui-select for showing list of states. My state list is greater than ui-select dropdown height. How can I show the scrollbar inside ui-select drop down list so that user knows there are more items in the list?

Comment: set a css property `overflow:scroll`.

Comment: use overflow:scroll, If it is for touch device use -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch. still your facing the problem. Please post the code to rectify

Comment: @HP's411: What element should receive the `overflow:scroll` property?

Comment: @jkndrkn :  The Container which has large amount of Data to Show on it. For Example you have a `<DIV>` which will holds your Data, than this `<DIV>` should receive this Property.

Answer (score 1):

Add below css code

```
.ui-select-choices-content{
 overflow-y:scroll !important;
 &::-webkit-scrollbar
 {
 width: 8px !important;
 }
 &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
 {
 border-radius: 7px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
 background-color: red;
 }
}
```